# MySQL Deleting based upon a query result

Tags: mysql, database, sql-delete

I have the following mysql query which finds the most recently modified and unique spawnpoint_id from a pokemon table in my database:

```
SELECT 
    t1.spawnpoint_id, t1.last_modified
FROM
    pokemon t1
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MAX(last_modified) last_modified, spawnpoint_id
    FROM
        pokemon
    GROUP BY spawnpoint_id) t2 ON 
    t1.spawnpoint_id = t2.spawnpoint_id
    AND t1.last_modified = t2.last_modified;
```

I get the results I want with the above....  but now, I want to delete all records that *don't* match these results.

I have tried to enclose the query in a `DELETE .. NOT IN` something like this:

```
DELETE FROM pokemon WHERE (spawnpoint_id, last_modified) NOT IN (
SELECT 
    t1.spawnpoint_id, t1.last_modified
FROM
    pokemon t1
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MAX(last_modified) last_modified, spawnpoint_id
    FROM
        pokemon
    GROUP BY spawnpoint_id) t2 ON 
    t1.spawnpoint_id = t2.spawnpoint_id
    AND t1.last_modified = t2.last_modified) x;
```

but I'm getting MySQL syntax error.  I've been searching for a couple of hours, and finally hoped someone here might be able to help me discover what I'm doing wrong.  Many thanks.

EDIT: SHOW CREATE TABLE pokemon;

`CREATE TABLE pokemon (
   encounter_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   spawnpoint_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   pokemon_id int(11) NOT NULL,
   latitude double NOT NULL,
   longitude double NOT NULL,
   disappear_time datetime NOT NULL,
   individual_attack int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   individual_defense int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   individual_stamina int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   move_1 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   move_2 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   last_modified datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   time_detail int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (encounter_id),
   KEY pokemon_spawnpoint_id (spawnpoint_id),
   KEY pokemon_pokemon_id (pokemon_id),
   KEY pokemon_disappear_time (disappear_time),
   KEY pokemon_last_modified (last_modified),
   KEY pokemon_time_detail (time_detail),
   KEY pokemon_latitude_longitude (latitude,longitude)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please update the post with the actual error.

Comment: The query is awkward. If you want to delete rows from table1 that don't exist in table2, simply do: DELETE FROM tablle1 WHERE (table1.spawnpoint_id, table1.last_modified) NOT IN (
    SELECT table2.spawnpoint_id, table2.last_modified from table2)

Comment: The error seems to be: "Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'pokemon' for update in FROM clause" ...which is why I thought that adding 'x' would solve that. In regards to the 'awkward' query, maybe so. I want to delete all records in the pokemon table with distinct  'spawnpoint_id' *except* the most recent 'last_modified' ones ... I can select those records as I described, just don't know the best way to now delete the ones that are *not* them...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you use table `pokemon`, from which you want to delete rows, in the from-part of a subquery (which is not permitted).

One could get around this by first doing an update-statement that marks the rows to be deleted, and then do a separate delete statement. Note that the "must not use in the from-part"-restriction also applies to update-statements. Yet this can be solved by using a join rather than a subselect as follows:

```sql
create table a (
  x int,
  y int
);

insert into a (x,y) values (1,2),(3,4);

update a a1, (select max(a2.x) as x from a a2) a3 set a1.y = 0 where a1.x = a3.x;

delete from a where y=0
```

Comment: Stephan, thank you.  Unfortunately, this answer flys over my head.  I like the idea of marking the rows to be deleted (maybe just add a new column?) and use a similar insert statement and then execute the delete... I'll experiment.